# How to display an element behind a fixed parent?

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

Illustrated: how to display a logo contour (children of logo) behind a menu background?

The logo is part of a centered menu but not necessarily at the middle (depends of menu item names), so for me best solution is to still the contour inside the logo div like this:

```
<img src="background-image.jpg">
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="contour"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

I have browsed dozens of solutions for similar issues offered on stackoverflow but none seems to fit… At this point, I tried to set `z-index`, to move `div.contour` out of `div.logo`, to set `.contour` as pseudo-class `:before` or `:after`, to set a `position: absolute` for `.contour` or to play with `overflow: hidden`. Is there a CSS solution (without using JS)?

[JSFiddle Sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/klemart3d/28msjLg2/)

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution would be working with one background SVG for the dark and light green shape and the orange contour. That background would be centered via CSS.

That whole "contour partially around two different shaped elements" looks to me undoable with normal browser (perhaps some mask magic via CSS...)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always trick it, adding first a `before` pseudoelement to hide the top part of your circle and then add  `after` pseudoelement to cover your circle with another one without border.

like this:

```css
* {
  position: relative;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: darkcyan;
  border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: cadetblue;
}
.anotherclass:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  background-color:darkcyan;
  height:50px;
  width:110px;
  position:absolute;
      top: -16px;
    left: -5px;  
}
.anotherclass:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  background-color:trasparent;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: cadetblue;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px; 
}

.contour {
  border: 5px solid orange;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/0b3/burning-tree-1377053.jpg" width="100%">
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>
      <div class="logo anotherclass">
        <div class="logo contour"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Notice I added another class to your html as you have 2 "logo" classes (parent and child). You may correct this if you like.

If you have problems with the image of your logo now, you could place it trough `background-image` as a property in the `after` pseudoelement or if you use html `<img>` z-index should work probably fine to place it above `after` pseudoelement.

Comment: Not so bad workaround, thank you. But `.anotherclass:after` seems useless, when I delete it and I set your `.anotherclass:before` with `z-index: -1` and `.contour` to `z-index: -2` I have the same result:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/klemart3d/40yLv3us/)

Comment: Up to you how to implement it. the answer were to give a solution which it does. I personally never use negative z-index values. often unexpected behaviours cross platform. too often